# Gstreamer 1.14.4 - Splitmuxsink not creating multiple files

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Splitmuxsink is not creating multiple files of desired length, rather it is creating single file with the original stream length.I am using splitmuxsink's signal 'location-format-full' to retrieve the PTS of buffers and also buffers from identity to check the pts.  I have used dynamic linking for the rtspsrc and rtph264depay. Is the code attached ,correct ?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static void cb_new_rtspsrc_pad(GstElement *element,GstPad*pad,gpointer  data)
{
gchar *name;
GstElement *p_rtph264depay;

name = gst_pad_get_name(pad);
g_print("A new pad %s was created\n", name);
p_rtph264depay = GST_ELEMENT(data);

if(!gst_element_link_pads(element, name, p_rtph264depay, "sink"))
{
    printf("Failed to link elements 3\n");
}
g_free(name);
}

  static void pts_analysis_cb(GstElement *splitmuxsink, guint id , GstSample *sample,  gpointer user_data)   
  {
  GstBuffer *buffer=gst_sample_get_buffer(sample); 
  GstClockTime pts1 = GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer);
  printf("lff - *%ld*   \n  ",pts1);
  gst_println("Hello from above");
  }

static void pts_analysis_call(GstElement *identity,  GstBuffer *buffer, gpointer user_data) 
    {
   GstClockTime pts = GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer);
    printf("id- *%ld* ",pts);
}

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline,*rtspsrc,*depay,*h264,*splitmux,*id;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  pipeline=gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

  rtspsrc=gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc","src");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(rtspsrc),"location","rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test",NULL);

 depay=gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay","depay");
 id=gst_element_factory_make("identity","id");
  h264=gst_element_factory_make("h264parse","h264");

  splitmux=gst_element_factory_make("splitmuxsink","mux");
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(splitmux),"location","/home/fti/gstpatch/video%02d.mp4","max-size-time","6000000000",NULL);

  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);

  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),rtspsrc,depay,NULL);
  g_signal_connect(rtspsrc,"pad-added",G_CALLBACK(cb_new_rtspsrc_pad),depay);
  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),id,NULL);
  printf("*%d*",gst_element_link(depay,id));
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),h264,NULL);
  printf("*%d*",gst_element_link(id,h264));

    g_signal_connect_data(id, "handoff",G_CALLBACK(pts_analysis_call), NULL, NULL, G_CONNECT_AFTER);

  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),splitmux,NULL);
  if(!gst_element_link(h264,splitmux))
   { printf("Failed");}

  g_signal_connect_data(splitmux,"format-location-full", G_CALLBACK(pts_analysis_cb),NULL,NULL,G_CONNECT_AFTER);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  if (msg != NULL)
  {
  gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  }
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
  }
```

The output:

```
./run
*1**1*A new pad recv_rtp_src_0_3739157605_14 was created

Failed to link elements 3

A new pad recv_rtp_src_1_4067307517_96 was created

id- *284978620* id- *288409482* lff - *284978620*   
  Hello from above
id- *330106510* id- *494942923* id- *410824070*
```

The splitmuxsink does not seem to get any frames after the first one.

Comment: Since you say in general it is running lets assume the building of the pipeline is fine. What can you tell about the source? What is the original duration in the first place? Can you verify the source has proper sync points (IDR-frames)? For guaranteeing proper playable segments splitmuxsink will only split at sync points.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the duration of the video segments with time or bytes using the 
properties `max-size-bytes` and/or `max-size-time` like in this example:

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(app_context->sink), "max-size-time",(uint64_t)app_context->segment_duration_sec * NANO_SECOND, NULL);
```